# How to fix - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method addObserver must be called on the main thread. Trying to integrate GooglePay using Strip API

Tags: android, google-pay

## Calling Google Pay Stripe API in java

```
public void StripePayment(JSONObject paymentDetails) {
  Log.d(" paymentDetails App №", String.valueOf(paymentDetails));
  String PUBLISHABLE_KEY = "xxxxx";
// Stripe API calls for Google Pay
  PaymentConfiguration.init(pContext, PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
  final GooglePayPaymentMethodLauncher googlePayLauncher = new GooglePayPaymentMethodLauncher(this, new GooglePayPaymentMethodLauncher.Config(GooglePayEnvironment.Test, "US","Some Inc"),this::onGooglePayReady, this::onGooglePayResult) 
     googlePayLauncher.present("USD",amount);      
}
```

Comment: Can you share the log and if the code that you've shared, is not the code that's producing the error, the code that's producing the error also?